# Sql PIVOT multi columns with keyword search

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I've a units table as follows:

[image]

I'm using following query to return the search results but it creates separate rows for alt units.

```
SELECT U.unit_id as primary_unit_id, U.unit_name as primary_unit,  
    alt_id1 = (select top 1 unit_id from T_DX_UNITS where alt_of=U.unit_id and alt_sort_no=1),
    alt_unit1 = (select top 1 unit_name from T_DX_UNITS where alt_of=U.unit_id and alt_sort_no=1),
    alt_conversion1 = (select top 1 conversion from T_DX_UNITS where alt_of=U.unit_id and alt_sort_no=1),
    alt_id2 = (select top 1 unit_id from T_DX_UNITS where alt_of=U.unit_id and alt_sort_no=2),
    alt_unit2 = (select top 1 unit_name from T_DX_UNITS where alt_of=U.unit_id and alt_sort_no=2),
    alt_conversion2 = (select top 1 conversion from T_DX_UNITS where alt_of=U.unit_id and alt_sort_no=2),
    alt_id3 = (select top 1 unit_id from T_DX_UNITS where alt_of=U.unit_id and alt_sort_no=3),
    alt_unit3 = (select top 1 unit_name from T_DX_UNITS where alt_of=U.unit_id and alt_sort_no=3),
    alt_conversion3 = (select top 1 conversion from T_DX_UNITS where alt_of=U.unit_id and alt_sort_no=3),
    alt_id4 = (select top 1 unit_id from T_DX_UNITS where alt_of=U.unit_id and alt_sort_no=4),
    alt_unit4 = (select top 1 unit_name from T_DX_UNITS where alt_of=U.unit_id and alt_sort_no=4),
    alt_conversion4 = (select top 1 conversion from T_DX_UNITS where alt_of=U.unit_id and alt_sort_no=4)
FROM T_DX_UNITS U
WHERE --U.alt_of IS NULL AND 
(U.unit_name LIKE @keyword + '%' OR U.unit_name LIKE '%' + @keyword + '%')
```

Which gives following output: (first row is correct which is showing alt units as well but it also shows separate rows for alt units)

[image]

**UPDATES ON REQUEST**
Desired result: (It works without filter as follows which is correct)
[image]

[SQL FIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/26938/10)

Comment: What's wrong with commented `U.alt_of IS NULL` to exclude alt units?

Comment: @Serg It won't search in the primary units then.

Comment: My guess was "primary" == `U.alt_of IS NULL`. If it's not the case, what is primary then?

Comment: @Serg yes, you're correct. primary = `U.alt_of IS NULL` and secondary means `NOT NULL`. But it should find in both primary and secondary units. Twist is even if it find in secondary we must need to show primary unit along with that secondary unit matched.

Comment: Can you show your desired results?

Comment: Your current (commented) query shows both primary unit along with secondary. What exactly must be excluded? Primary which ... ? Secondary which .. ?

Comment: @GarethD question updated. It works without keyword search but when I search for any units, it shows duplicate rows as shown in sql fiddle.

Comment: @Serg Sorry for confusion. We can consider primary when `alt_of = NULL`, secondary means alternative units which is `alt_of != NULL` and `alt_sort_no` column show no if alt like 1 = alt1, 2=alt2 and so on.

Comment: If you can get your desired results by running a query and taking a screenshot, I don't really understand why you need our help. You already have a query that produces your desired results.

Comment: @GarethD It's working without search.. when I search through unit_name, it shows separate rows for secondary (alt) units. That's the problem. It should show both primary of secondary unit if it matches secondary units.

Comment: Then what you have shown is not your desired results. Please can you show your desired results when you have the search term.

Comment: @GarethD I just show you sample result structure. Obviously result will be based on search terms. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a guess. Probably you need also primary units which don't satisfy the filter themself but some of it's alt units do satisfy.

```
DECLARE @keyword nvarchar(10) = 'unit';
WITH alts AS (
   SELECT [unit_id], [unit_name], [conversion],[alt_of], [alt_sort_no] 
   FROM T_DX_UNITS 
   WHERE alt_of IS NOT NULL AND unit_name LIKE '%' + @keyword + '%'
)
SELECT U.unit_id as primary_unit_id, U.unit_name as primary_unit,  
    alt_id1,
    alt_unit1,
    alt_conversion1,
    alt_id2,
    alt_unit2 ,
    alt_conversion2,
    alt_id3,
    alt_unit3,
    alt_conversion3
    alt_id4,
    alt_unit4,
    alt_conversion4
FROM T_DX_UNITS U
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT 
    alt_id1 = (select top 1 unit_id from alts a where a.alt_of=U.unit_id and a.alt_sort_no=1),
    alt_unit1 =      (select top 1 unit_name from alts a where a.alt_of=U.unit_id and a.alt_sort_no=1),
    alt_conversion1 =(select top 1 conversion from alts a where a.alt_of=U.unit_id and a.alt_sort_no=1),
    alt_id2 =        (select top 1 unit_id from alts a where a.alt_of=U.unit_id and a.alt_sort_no=2),
    alt_unit2 =      (select top 1 unit_name from alts a where a.alt_of=U.unit_id and a.alt_sort_no=2),
    alt_conversion2 =(select top 1 conversion from alts a where a.alt_of=U.unit_id and a.alt_sort_no=2),
    alt_id3 =        (select top 1 unit_id from alts a where a.alt_of=U.unit_id and a.alt_sort_no=3),
    alt_unit3 =      (select top 1 unit_name from alts a where a.alt_of=U.unit_id and a.alt_sort_no=3),
    alt_conversion3 =(select top 1 conversion from alts a where a.alt_of=U.unit_id and a.alt_sort_no=3),
    alt_id4 =        (select top 1 unit_id from alts a where a.alt_of=U.unit_id and a.alt_sort_no=4),
    alt_unit4 =      (select top 1 unit_name from alts a where a.alt_of=U.unit_id and a.alt_sort_no=4),
    alt_conversion4 =(select top 1 conversion from alts a where a.alt_of=U.unit_id and a.alt_sort_no=4)
    ) t
WHERE U.alt_of IS NULL 
AND (U.unit_name LIKE '%' + @keyword + '%' 
    OR coalesce(t.alt_id1, t.alt_id2, t.alt_id3, t.alt_id4) IS NOT NULL)
```

Comment: It looks like perfect, however I'll test with different conditions. BIG THANKS!!